# Reference specific String value inside separate XML file in Android

Tags: android, xml

Inside my `res\values` folder, I want to place multiple `.xml` files with duplicate `<string>` names.

i.e. The `.xml` file `example1.xml` will have a string resource of:

`<string name="title">Test Example 1</string>`

At the same time, I want the `.xml` file `Example2.xml` to also have a string resource of the same name, but different value:

`<string name="title">Test Example 2</string>`

Both `.xml` files will live in `res\values` and I want to access the string values programmatically.

I know how to reference the string resource via: `R.string.title`, but how do I specify from which `.xml` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android, you can only reference `Strings` using value provided in `name` attribute of the `String` resource  and **NOT** using name of the XML file. So you can't specify the name of the XML file to reference the `String`, you just need to have different values for `name` attribute of each `String` resource.

**Quote from *developer.android.com***

> A string is a simple resource that is referenced using the value
>   provided in the name attribute (not the name of the XML file). So, you
>   can combine string resources with other simple resources in the one
>   XML file, under one  element.